# C - Convert this char to an int for a dynamic array

Tags: c, arrays, io, dynamic-arrays

I am creating a dynamic array but I set the 'id' as a char when it must be an int (between 1000000 and 9999999), and now I cannot figure out how to make it work as an int. The user enters a series of inputs which make up a record, to be stored in a dynamic array.

This is part of my code:

```
typedef struct {
    char last[NAMESIZE]; /* 1 non-empty word */
    char first[NAMESIZE]; /* 1 non-empty word */
} name;

typedef struct {
    int id; /* ID between 1000000 & 9999999 inclusive */
    name name; 
    int score; /* between 0 & 100 inclusive */
} record;

typedef struct {
    record *data;   /* pointer to dynamic array of records */
    size_t nalloc;  /* number of records allocated */ 
    size_t nused;   /* number of records used */
    /* add any additional members you think necessary */
} record_list;

int data_input() {
    id and instead of sizeof just a number between 1000000 and 9999999*/
    char id[7];
    char fname[NAMESIZE];
    char lname[NAMESIZE];
    int score;
    int idvalid = 0;
    int lnvalid = 0;
    int fnvalid = 0;
    int svalid = 0;

    name name1;
    record rec;
    /* ID */
    do {
    fprintf(stderr, "Enter an ID.\n");
    scanf("%s", id);
    /* if id is int get rid or isdigit and strlens */
    if ((!isdigit(*id) || strlen(id) != 7) && (*id != '0')) {
        data_input();
        /* reset id */
    } else if (strlen(id) == 1 && *id == '0') {
        prompt();
        return 0;
    } else {
        idvalid = 1;
    }
    } while (idvalid != 1);

    /* Last Name */
    do {
    fprintf(stderr, "Enter a last name.\n");
    scanf("%s", lname);
    if (!isalpha(*lname) || strlen(lname) > NAMESIZE) {

    } else {
        strcpy(name1.last, lname);
        lnvalid = 1;
    }
    } while (lnvalid != 1);
    /* First Name */
    do {
    fprintf(stderr, "Enter a first name.\n");
    scanf("%s", fname);
    if (!isalpha(*fname) || strlen(fname) > NAMESIZE) {

    } else {
        strcpy(name1.first, fname);
        fnvalid = 1;
    }
    } while (fnvalid != 1);
    /* Score */
    do {
    fprintf(stderr, "Enter a score.\n");
    scanf("%d", &score);
    if ((!isdigit(score)) || (score < 0 || score > 100)) {

    } else {
        svalid = 1;
    }
    } while (svalid != 1);
    return 1;
}

int main(void) {
    record_list list;
    list_init(&list);
    prompt();
}
```

So the char id[7] in data_input must be made an int like id in the record struct. What would you change to make this work? I tried many things but the the program just wont work properly.

Edit: another issue I'm having is that for score, is that all input is invalid except for 55? It is supposed to be any number from 0-100.

Comment: Do not input number between `1000000` and `9999999` to `char id[7];` via `scanf("%s", id);` The buffer is too small to store such a null-terminated string.

Comment: `sscanf()` and `atoi()` are useful to convert string to integer.

Comment: `(!isdigit(score))` won't be what you want to do. Check the return value of `scanf()` to see if the input was successful.